# Why does my browser cache fill up so fast?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, performance, browser-cache

So on my second desktop there seems to be a problem with the browser cache. 
To clear up the cache i'm using this program called ccleaner. Helps me alot keeping everything clean. Recently the browser cache was filling up so fast that i could run ccleaner twice a day and it would clean over 400mb of cache every run. This is without absurd internet browsing. probably max 2 hours of browsing a day.

After a while the pc starts to get slower and slower and when i run ccleaner it seems to fix this problem. The problem is that i will have to run it at least twice a day to keep my pc running smooth.

How is this possible and what can i do to fix this?

I'm using chrome aswell as firefox by the way.

Answer (score 2):

2 hours of browsing and 400MB cache translate to an average of 56KByte/s while browsing. Seems pretty legit to me.

If you suspect that the cache does not only fill up because of browsing, you should consider scanning your PC for Viruses/Malware.

The accumulation of 400MB of Cache should really not slow down your Computer, unless your hard disk is running out of space.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I already scanned for malware/spyware but nothing was found. I will now try and see how many space my hard disk has left. Has te slow speed got something to do with the memory that's allocated to the cache?